# Traceback (most recent call last): in <module> assistant.train_model()

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, module

I got two errors in my python Codes. It is a simple Intelligent Voice Assistant. Could you please help me to resolve these problems?
Codes are in the images below:

[Image 1, Line 109](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlZNm.png)

[Image 2, Line 67](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjj9F.png)

Comment: I'm shooting blind without knowing the module, but try correcting the typo, it's 'intents.json', not 'intents.jason'

Comment: Please [edit] to post the codes and the error messages as **TEXT**, not images. Also, [edit] to show the value of `self.intents`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without more information, but it appears that `self.intents` is a string instead of a dictionary as expected. Therefore, searching for the key 'intents', you are indexing a string with the index 'intents' when a string index should be an integer.